# $\arctan(n/x)$ in terms of $\arctan(1/x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to make use of an algorithm that solves the $\arctan \left ( \frac {1}{x} \right)$ problem with a specified precision, to solve $\arctan \left ( \frac {n}{x} \right )$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

Can $\arctan \left( \frac {n}{x} \right )$ be decomposed and expressed in terms of $\arctan \left( \frac {1}{x} \right )$?

EDIT:
I'm writing software code that implements an efficient algorithm for calculating $\arctan \left ( \frac {1}{x} \right)$ with a very high floating-point precision, and I'm trying to tweak this code to also calculate $\arctan \left ( \frac {n}{x} \right)$. So far, my tweaks to the algorithm have resulted in a huge drop in performance when calculating for thousands of decimal places.

Comment: What are the allowed operations?  I mean, one answer is just compute $\arctan(n\tan(\arctan(1/x)))$, which is silly, but you haven't ruled it out.

Comment: I am interested in the simplest possible forms, preferably limited to the basic arithmetic operations and arctan(1/x). A fictitious example:
`n * (arctan(1/n) + arctan(1/x))`

Comment: This question needs clarification. Do you mean that you have software to compute $\arctan(1/y)$ for any $y$? In that case, just feed it $y=x/n$, and you will get $\arctan(n/x)$. Or if it's a “multiplication formula” for $\arctan(nt)$ that you want, look at the argument of the complex number $(1+it)^n$.

Comment: @HansLundmark
I edited my original question. To further clarify, yes, it computes **arctan(1/y)** for any **integer y**. The algorithm in question deals with integer numbers, and I have not been successful in tweaking it to process float input, so feeding it **y = x/n** does not work (for now).

Comment: OK, that makes things clearer.

Comment: For what it's worth, I rewrote the whole routine from scratch by implementing the Maclaurin and Euler series for arctan(z), found here:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangent.html and here: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/aukil/papers/conf/2011_IEEE-ISIE11_Fast-arctan.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $x\gg1$. Then $\alpha:=\arctan{1\over x}$ is a small quantity. Using Mathematica you obtain the following series for 
$\arctan{n\over x}=\arctan(n\>\tan\alpha)$:
$$\eqalign{\arctan{n\over x}&=\cr &n\alpha+{n-n^3\over3}\alpha^3+{2n-5n^3+3n^5\over 15}\alpha^5+{17n-77n^3+105 n^5-45n^7\over315}\alpha^7+\ ?\alpha^9\ .\cr}$$

Comment: Thank you for this interesting series. Unfortunately, it looks like an infinite one which would be quite taxing to compute for a high decimal-places precision factor.